# Add data to self created HTML object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a reason this doesn't work ?

```
 var link = $('<a href="#" class="choose-delivery-pickup">Kies</a>');
            link.data('name', address.name);
            link.data('street', address.street);
            link.data('number', address.nr);
            link.data('zip', address.zip);
            link.data('city', address.city);

var message = $('<div style="min-width:150px;"><address><strong>' + address.name + '</strong><br>' + address.street + ' ' + address.nr + '<br>' + address.zip + ' ' + address.city + '</address>' + String(link) + '</div>');
```

returns:

```
    <div style="min-width:150px;" class="">
      <address>
        <strong>John</strong><br>
          Street 81<br>
          Doe Doe
      </address>
      [object Object]
    </div>
```

the address parameters are filled with normal strings so there is no problem there.

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What behaviour do you expect? What behaviour do you get?

Answer (score 0):

If you're expecting that *attributes* will be added by that code, that's not what `data` does. `data` never *writes* to `data-*` attributes, it just uses them for initialization. After initialization, there is no connection between the data managed by `data` and `data-*` attributes.

If you want attributes, use `link.attr("data-name", address.name)` and such instead.

But if you're just worried that you're not seeing the data on the element when you inspect it, but you're happy using `data`, your code does work. jQuery manages the data cache in a way that isn't shown in the DOM inspector. Example:

```js
var address = {name: "address name"};

var link = $('<a href="#" class="choose-delivery-pickup">Kies</a>');
link.data('name', address.name);
display(link.data('name')); // "address name"


function display(msg) {
  $("<p>").html(String(msg)).appendTo(document.body);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```